# How to handle Deadlocks using the javascript neo4j driver?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I'm using the javascript neo4j-driver and sometimes I'm facing this error :

```
Neo4jError: ForsetiClient[3] can't acquire ExclusiveLock{owner=ForsetiClient[0]} on INDEX_ENTRY(5454851920060587002), because holders of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient[3].\n Wait list:ExclusiveLock[\nClient[0] waits for [3]]
```

how can i handle that using javascript and thank you !

Comment: I believe that's a server-side issue, maybe caused by some of your queries. Do you run queries in parallel that affect the same nodes and/or relationships?

Comment: yes that's it !

Comment: So you'll need some kind of coordination. If you can afford it, do not run these queries in parallel. Any transaction on particular nodes and relationships will set a lock on them, so other transactions have to wait.